# If $\int_0^1 f(x) dx=\frac{3}{2}$, could we say anything about $\int_0^1 x^2 f(x)dx$?

Tags: calculus

Suppose $\int_0^1 f(x) dx=\frac{3}{2}$. Could you find $\int_0^1 x^2 f(x)dx$?

***What I attempted:-***

I am assuming the additional assumption that **$f$ is continuous**. However, not all $R$-integrable functions are continuous.

By **Mean Value Theorem for Integrals**, $\exists c\in (0,1)$ such that $f(c)=\int_0^1 f(x)=\frac{3}{2}$.

Moreover, $x^2$ does not change its sign in $(0,1)$. So, by **Weighted Mean Value Theorem**, $\exists \xi \in (0,1)$ such that $\int_0^1 x^2 f(x)dx=f(\xi)\int_0^1 x^2 dx=\frac{1}{3} \times f(\xi)$. One of my fellow mates assumed that $c=\xi$ and hence concluded that $\int_0^1 x^2 f(x)dx=\frac{1}{3} \times f(\xi)=\frac{1}{3} \times \frac{3}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$. I do not see anything vivid which clearly tells us that $c$ and $\xi$ may be same.

Comment: you could not find $\int_0^1 x^2 f(x)dx$ exactly, only bounds for it. Think of suitable $f$, one that is increasing and has a maximum at $x=1$, another $f$ that is decreasing and has a minimum at $x=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't much you can conclude.

For example, if $f$ is constant, then $\int_0^1 x^2f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac12$.  On the other hand, if $f(x)=3x$ then $\int_0^1 x^2f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac34$.

If $f$ is non-negative but not almost everywhere zero, the simple bound $0<x^2f(x)<f(x)$ for all $0<x<1$ with $f(x)>0$ gives $$0<\int_0^1 x^2f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x<\int_0^1 f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac32$$
and every possible value is achieved by some $f=\frac3{2\lvert I\rvert}\mathbf{1}_I$, $I$ a subinterval of $[0,1]$.
However, if $f$ can change sign, then we don't even have a bound -- for example,
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
c+\frac32 & x\in[1-\frac1n,1]\\
\frac32-c & x\in[0,\frac1n]\\
\frac32 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
where $\lvert c\rvert,n$ are large.